# inherit properties from class other than parent

Tags: css

Say I have two classes in my CSS, say `.classA{}` and `.classB{}`, and I've defined and tailored `classA` to however I like it. Now I'd like `classB` to be mostly like `classA`, with a couple of changes. Since they will be used separately (i.e., A is not the parent of B), B won't inherit properties from A in the layout. Can I do something like

```
.classB{
    from .classA inherit *
    some additional changes
}
```

while writing the CSS, which will avoid having to copy/paste and also ensure that if I were to change A sometime later, B changes automatically and I don't have to keep track of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS has no concept of variables to allow for the adjusting of one CSS measurement to influence others automatically. However, there are CSS writing systems that allow for variables (that are then 'compiled' and spit out plain CSS). Those are useful, but require use of the particular framework. (one example: http://lesscss.org/ )

If you are using a server side scripting language such as PHP, you could write your CSS files as PHP files, using variables within.

Barring that, I'd use multiple classes:

```
.sharedStyles {...the styles to be the same on elements}
.uniqueStylesA {...}
.uniqueStylesB {...}
```

Then apply as such:

```
<div class="sharedStyles uniqueStylesA">...</div>
<div class="sharedStyles uniqueStylesB">...</div>
```

Or...if you can nest in your HTML:

```
<div class="sharedStyles">
    <div class="uniqueStylesA">...</div>
    <div class="uniqueStylesB">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the multiple classes is cool. I did not know you could assign multiple classes to a div. What happens when there's a conflict? Does it use the value defined in the last class in the list?

Comment: There's never a conflict as there's the cascade see: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cascade Using multiple classes can make for a much leaner CSS file. It's also useful for using OOCSS: http://www.slideshare.net/stubbornella/object-oriented-css

Comment: oh, to answer your follow-up question, yes, the later defined style in the CSS file would trump the one before it. That's part of the Cascade. So, in the example above, if I had given sharedStyles a background: brown and uniqueStylesB: pink, then the second DIV in my examples would have a pink bankground, as that style was declared after the brown style.